# Markov Chain -- Transient or Recurrent class?

Tags: markov-chains

Specify the classes of the Markov chain, and state whether they are recurrent or transient.

\begin{align*}
P_4=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

I have done three problems like this but I'm not sure if I'm correct. I'm just making sure I understand the idea of recurrent and transient *classes* as opposed to *states*. For this problem, I have

$\{0, 1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}$ for the classes. The first two are recurrent and the last two are transient.

Is this correct? If not, can someone explain what's wrong?

I obtained my solutions by drawing a diagram.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.